Set Notation for defining a set of differentiable real functions.
I am trying to define a set $C^\infty\left(-1, 3\right)$ using set notation such that it is a set of infinitely differentiable real-valued functions $f$ in the interval $(-1,3)$. For additional context, the set is meant to be presented as a subspace of the vector space $\ \mathbb{R}^{(-1,3)}$ later on.
An attempt I have been most confident with so far is:
$$C^\infty\left(-1,3\right) =\{f\ |\ \left(\mathit{f}:\left(-1,3\right)\to\mathbb{R}\right)\land\exists{f^{\left(n\right)} \ \forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}}\}$$
Any help would be appreciated.

The symbol $\exists$ cannot be used as you suggest if you want to be completely rigorous. For simplicity $I:=(-1,3)$. The cleanest way is
$$C^{\infty}(I)=\{f\in\mathbb{R}^I:\forall k\in \mathbb{N}\ (f\in C^k(-1,3))\}$$
Obviously you have first to define $C^k(-1,3)$ for any $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$.
$$C^0(I)=\left\{f\in\mathbb{R}^{I}:\forall x_0\in I\ \left(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)\right)\right\} $$
To define $C^k(I)$ for $k\geq 1$, it's useful to first define the set of functions defined on $I$ that admit a derivative
$$D(I):=\left\{f\in C^0(I):\forall x_0\in I\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\in \mathbb{R}\right)\right\}$$
Now we can define $C^1(I)$:
$$C^1(I)=\{f\in D(I):f^{(1)}\in C^0(I)\}$$
Now we can define inductively $C^{k+1}(I)$ from $C^k(I)$
$$C^{k+1}(I)=\{f\in C^{k}(I):f^{(k)}\in C^1(I)\},\ \ \ \ \ \ k\geq 1$$

Thanks for answering. For the last line defining the set of (k+1)-times differentiable functions, why does it not have the condition that the (k+1)th derivative should be an element of the set of k-times differentiable functions, instead of the set condition that has been used ? Also, is a non-recursive/ non-inductive definition for the set of infinitely differentiable functions possible?

You mean the first derivative should be an element of the set of $k$-times continously differentiable functions? Like this $C^{k+1}(I)={f\in C^k(I):f^{(1)}\in C^k(I)}$? This is also a perfectly fine option. For the non-recursive approach I don't know.
